# SQL Server management studio 2016 not working

Tags: windows, sql-server

I have windows 7, I have tried uninstalling, re-installing multiple times, tried to repair. I always get this error below. I have tried installing .NET 4.6.2, .NET 4.6.1, and both 4.6.2, 4.6.1 multi targeting packs. Still get the same error.

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  
------------------------------  

Failed to open connection dialog.  

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio)
```

Comment: Where do you see this error?

Comment: Also, are you aware that SQL Server 2016 is not supported on Windows 7? SSMS 2016 is supported if you have SP1.

Comment: I have Windows 7 enterprise SP1

Comment: The error pops up as soon as the application starts up.